# How to POST data on database using Postman with laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

I try to POST data to database with "form-data" on  "postman" with Laravel 9, and I try to return the data to JSON.

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\M_Barang;

class Utama extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('Utama');
    }
    
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|max:2048'
        ]);
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $tujuan_upload = 'data_file';
        if ($file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file)) {
            $data = M_Barang::create([
                'nama_produk' => $request->nama_produk,
                'harga' => $request->harga,
                'gambar' => $nama_file
            ]);
            $res['message'] = "succsess!";
            $res['values'] = $data;
            return response($res);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

This is my expected result:

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send data from raw section in JSON Format, and try to send your image in base64 format (because its very convenient way to store a image into file system via the API).

Example:`{"profile_pic":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh (base64 image string)"}`

you can convert base64 image here https://www.base64-image.de/
and in Android and iOS has some libraries for converting image to base 64 while sending data to API

Welcome in Advance.

Comment: but normal api should accept all kind of image format, right?

Comment: yes, your right above code of mine accept all kind of image format but when i store to as file is converted/saved as png format.

Answer (score -1):

In Postman's headers section, you have to set `Accept` and `content-type` to `application/json`:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuUKW.png)

Comment: It's still the same

Comment: try to add Accept header: `Accept: application/json`